# Manifest fallbacks for screen orientation

Tags: android

In the [documentation for the Android manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), there are multiple different ways to specify `screenOrientation`:

- `landscape`
- `sensorLandscape` added in API 9
- `userLandscape` added in API 18

How can I specify `userLandscape`, but on older versions of Android, have it fallback to `sensorLandscape`, and on even older versions fall back to `landscape`? I couldn't find how to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that there's a way to implement the fallback mechanism in the manifest itself.

I would suggest that you specify one of { userLandscape, sensorLandscape, landscape } in the manifest. Then, check for the version at runtime and improvise.

Say, you decide to go with `android:screenOrientation="userLandscape"` in the manifest.

In your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)`, before setting the content:

```
int sdkInt = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

// if we're running on some API level within [9, 18), use `sensorLandscape`
if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD /* 9 */ 
        && sdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 /* 18 */) {
    setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
} else if (sdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD /* 9 */) {
    setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

// API 18 or above - handled in manifest

setContentView(R.layout.whatever);
```

Hope that someone comes up with a better solution than this. This seems brute-force.

**Edit:**

Tried a different approach - from what I know (and I could be wrong here), enums such as `userLandscape`, `sensorLandscape` etc. won't change values. As they currently stand:

```
<attr name="screenOrientation">
    <enum name="unspecified" value="-1" />
    <enum name="landscape" value="0" />
    <enum name="portrait" value="1" />
    <enum name="user" value="2" />
    <enum name="behind" value="3" />
    <enum name="sensor" value="4" />
    <enum name="nosensor" value="5" />
    <enum name="sensorLandscape" value="6" />
    <enum name="sensorPortrait" value="7" />
    <enum name="reverseLandscape" value="8" />
    <enum name="reversePortrait" value="9" />
    <enum name="fullSensor" value="10" />
    <enum name="userLandscape" value="11" />
    <enum name="userPortrait" value="12" />
    <enum name="fullUser" value="13" />
    <enum name="locked" value="14" />
</attr>
```

So, if you were to define an `integer` such as:

```
<!-- `0` for `landscape` -- defined in values/integers.xml -->
<integer name="customScreenOrientation">0</integer>

<!-- `6` for `sensorLandscape` -- defined in values-v9/integers.xml -->
<integer name="customScreenOrientation">6</integer>

<!-- `11` for `userLandscape` -- defined in values-v18/integers.xml -->
<integer name="customScreenOrientation">11</integer>
```

You could then use `@integer/customScreenOrientation` as the value for `android:screenOrientation` in your activity's tag.

Needless to say its a hack at best. If someone could confirm the steady status of enum values for `screenOrientation`, this could be a viable workaround - preferable to including code from my earlier suggestion in multiple activities.

**Yet another edit:**

The second approach I mentioned earlier can be improved upon:

Instead of multiple `integers.xml` files, create 3 `styles.xml` files. I guess you already have one - `values/styles.xml`. Create `values-v9/styles.xml` & `values-v18/styles.xml`.

```
<!-- values/styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">landscape</item>
</style>

<!-- values-v9/styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">sensorLandscape</item>
</style>

<!-- values-v18/styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">userLandscape</item>
</style>
```

Following this, create `values/integers.xml`(one file) and define an integer `customScreenOrientation`:

```
<integer name="customScreenOrientation">?android:attr/screenOrientation</integer>
```

You activity tag will look like:

```
<activity
    ....
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="@integer/customScreenOrientation"/>
```

The advantage of this approach over the second one is that we get to use the enums in place of hard-coded values. Again, these two approaches are equivalent if enum-values are set in stone. If they do change, the second approach will fail while the third one keeps on going.

Comment: This works. I would be interested in seeing a more elegant solution, but maybe there isn't one.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was playing around with this some more and found another workaround - its not elegant in my opinion, but does provide a solution with less code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Added another (the last I hope) way of implementing the fallback mechanism.

Comment: I think I still like the first one the best for compactness. In fact, I think maybe the manifest could be avoided altogether, and just have a three-condition if-else block all in one spot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree. The first approach, along with your changes would be best. I was checking if an xml-only solution was possible - and added the other approaches for completeness sake.